# Nested array andices for non nested array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Heres something I'm trying to teach myself. I want a pair of elements in the nested `indexArray` to point to elements inside the `numberArray`:

IOW : IF `indexArray` has `[[0,2],[3,4]]` I want the nested elements to point towards element `#0` and `#2` in `numberArray` and elements 3 and 4 in `numberArray`

```
    func findNumIndex(numberArray: [Int], indexArray: [[Int]]) -> Int {
       // Use the NESTED index elements to arrive at element index in numberArrray
    }

    findNumIndex(nums: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], queries: [[0,1],[1,2],[3,4]])

   // We would look at index 0 and 1, index 1 and 2, index 3 and 4 and get the numbers/
```

At first I thought about flattening the array, but that is NOT what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like something you can do with a simple `map`:

```
indexArray.map { $0.map { numberArray[$0] } }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. My suggestion: read up on the `map`, `flatMap`, `reduce`, and `filter` methods. They're really useful in a lot of situations!

Answer (score 0):

A bit over engineered, but this is a pretty handy extension that comes in a lot of circumstances:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Self.Index == Int {
    subscript<S: Sequence>(indices indices: S) -> [Self.Element]
        where S.Iterator.Element == Int {
        return indices.map{ self[$0] }
    }
}

let input = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let queries = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
let result = queries.map{ input[indices: $0] }

print(result) // => [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["d", "e"]]
```

Comment: Thats cool!  Thank you everybody! I have some good stuff to chew on.